# raphael moves div content down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, raphael

Probably super-basic question, but, why do the text on the first div of the table goes down when raphael creates its paper?

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function()  {
       raph = new Raphael('canvas_container', 600, 600);
     });
    </script>
    <title>Simple JS Page</title>
   </head>
   <body>
    <br>
  <div style="width: 100%; display: table;">
      <div style="display: table-row">
                        <div id="text_container" style="height:600px;width:300px;border: 8px solid #f7f7f7;display:table-cell;-webkit-border-radius:8px;-moz-border-radius:8px;border-radius:8px;vertical-align:text-top;">
       why am I in the bottom???
       </div>
       <div id="separator" style="height:600px;width:10px;display:table-cell">
       </div>
       <div id="canvas_container" style="height:600px;width:600px;border: 8px solid #f7f7f7;display: table-cell;-webkit-border-radius:8px;-moz-border-radius:8px;border-radius:8px;">
       </div> 
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The writing is in the top left for me.

Comment: I assume this code snippet has no access to jquery or raphael. To actually see the behavior I am seeing, you have to correct the paths of these two libraries and run locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the table-imitation css is getting in the way.  It looks like you are trying to create two vertical divs, one 300px wide the other 600px wide, with a 10px separator.  The same thing can be accomplished using floating, and it plays a little nicer with Raphael.

```
#text_container, #separator, #canvas_container{
    float: left;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q0aka3s6/